# Cannot Convert from System.Collection.GenericList to System.Predicate

Tags: c#, oop

I want to delete all elements  present in a list matching where clause using RemoveAll()

```
var show = Elements.Where((eq => (eq.ElementType == ElementType.Heavy)));
userElement.RemoveAll(show.ToList());
```

`Elements` is a list, `Heavy` is an enum type, `ElementType` is enum class.

Comment: I think you want this `userElement.RemoveAll((eq => (eq.ElementType == ElementType.Heavy)));`

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)` cannot accept a list. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=net-5.0

If you want to destructively remove elements, you can do the following:

```cs
userElement.RemoveAll(eq => eq.ElementType == ElementType.Heavy);
```